# Serialization of object to xml and string without \r\n special characters

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xmlwriter

I want to serialize my object to xml and then to a string.

```
  public class MyObject
  {
    [XmlElement]
    public string Name
    [XmlElement]
    public string Location;
  }
```

I want to obtain a **single line** string which will lok like this:

```
<MyObject><Name>Vladimir</Name><Location>Moskov</Location></MyObject>
```

I am using such code:

```
  XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
  settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
  settings.Indent = true;
  StringWriter StringWriter = new StringWriter();
  StringWriter.NewLine = ""; //tried to change it but without effect
  XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(StringWriter, settings);
  XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
  namespaces.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);
  XmlSerializer MySerializer= new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyObject ));
  MyObject myObject = new MyObject { Name = "Vladimir", Location = "Moskov" };

  MySerializer.Serialize(writer, myObject, namespaces);
  string s = StringWriter.ToString();
```

This is the closest what I get:

```
<MyObject>\r\n  <Name>Vladimir</Name>\r\n  <Location>Moskov</Location>\r\n</MyObject>
```

**I do know that I could remove "\r\n" from the string afterwards. But I would like to not produce them at all rather than removing them later.**

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could try:

```
settings.NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.None;
settings.Indent = false;
```

which for me, gives:

```
<MyObject><Name>Vladimir</Name><Location>Moskov</Location></MyObject>
```

Answer (score 10):

I used the input above, and here is a generic object to XML string method to be re-used anywhere:

```
public static string ObjectToXmlString(object _object)
{
    string xmlStr = string.Empty;

    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    settings.Indent = false;
    settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
    settings.NewLineChars = string.Empty;
    settings.NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.None;

    using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter())
    {
        using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter, settings))
        {
            XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            namespaces.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(_object.GetType());
            serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, _object, namespaces);

            xmlStr = stringWriter.ToString();
            xmlWriter.Close();
        }

        stringWriter.Close();
    }

    return xmlStr;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  It can be made extension method also.